# How to add another package manager to a ASP.NET MVC 6 project?

Tags: visual-studio, npm, asp.net-core-mvc, bower, jspm

There is currently two package managers under **Dependencies** in an ASP.NET MVC 6 application created with Visual Studio 2015 namely *Bower and NPM*. How can I add another package manager like [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) to the list and manage it's dependencies?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be done out of the box, as far as I'm aware, but maybe you would be happy enough with this visual studio 2015 extension: [Package Installer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/753b9720-1638-4f9a-ad8d-2c45a410fd74)